# Definition of $MachineEpsilon

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy, machine-precision

```
$MachineEpsilon
x = 0.0000000000000001
% + 1
% - 1
```

As expected the final result equals zero, since x < MachineEpsilon ($2.22045\times10^{-16}$).

However, if I double x (to 0.0000000000000002), then the final result should in my understanding still be zero, since x is still smaller than the MachineEpsilon, but... to my surprise the final result isn't zero! Question: why is this?

Note 1: If I triple x (to 0.0000000000000003), then x is larger than the MachineEpsilon and indeed the final result is bigger than zero.

Note 2: On my computer the value for MachineEpsilon is $2.22045\times10^{-16}$ Is this the same as on any computer using Mathematica by the way?

---

EDIT: I noticed that in **binary** form:

1. The MachineEpsilon is $1.\times2^{-52}$
2. And 0.0000000000000002 is $1.1100110100101011001\times2^{-53}$

Code:

```
BaseForm[$MachineEpsilon, 2]
x = BaseForm[0.0000000000000002, 2]
% + 1
BaseForm[% - 1, 2]
```

Therefore, could it be that $1.1100110100101011001\times2^{-53}$ is rounded up to $1.\times2^{-52}$ if $1$ is added? Which is precisely equal to the MachineEpsilon and that therefore the final result above with 0.0000000000000002 isn't zero but... the MachineEpsilon!?

Comment: In the past `$MachineEpsilon` in Windows-based and OS-X-based systems differed because the Windows-based systems used Intel processors and Apple used Motorola/IBM processors. Apple changed over to Intel in 2006. So now it would be hard to find a system running Mathematica that doesn't give ``2.220446049250313`*^-16`` for `$MachineEpsilon` because that is the value retuned by any system running an Intel Core i3, i5, or i7 processor(s).

Comment: `Log[2, $MachineEpsilon]` evaluates to `-52.` and `RootApproximant[$MachineEpsilon] === 2^-52` evaluates to `True`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose this is due to rounding. For as long as the value is smaller than half of `$MachineEpsilon` it yields 0, else it rounds up to `$MachineEpsilon`.

Given `x*i+1-1`

For, `i<0.5*10^15 $MachineEpsilon` I get zero,
while for `i>0.5*10^15 $MachineEpsilon` i get `$MachineEpsilon`.

And regarding your second question: On my laptop

> $MachineEpsilon = 2.22045×10−16

It might be a naive way to show it, but here's an illustration.

```
DiscretePlot[{(x*i) + 1 - 1}, {i, 1.1101, 1.11035, 0.000001}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

On a binary machine with $n$-bit floating point numbers, machine $\epsilon$ is the smallest number such that $1 + \epsilon$ can be represented in $n$ bits. This is
$$1.000\cdots01$$
where the length of $1$s and $0$s is $n$; in other words
$$1 + \epsilon = 2^0+2^{-(n-1)}\,.$$
For the standard [IEEE binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) floating point number $n = 53$ and
$$\epsilon = 2^{-52}\,.$$

So that's the story for binary machines.  When you start to investigate machine $\epsilon$ on such a machine using decimal numbers, you have to consider rounding error and how arithmetic operations are carried out.  Consider `1 * 10^-16` and `2 * 10^-16` in binary:

```
BaseForm[0.0000000000000001, 2]
BaseForm[0.0000000000000002, 2]
(*
  1.1100110100101011001 * 2^-54
  1.1100110100101011001 * 2^-53
*)
```

Now an arithmetic operation is carried out by the CPU with extra guard bits, so the the result is equal to the exact result of the operation rounded to $n$ bits.
So
$$\eqalign{
 1. &+\ 2. * 10^{-16} = \cr
  &1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001110011\cdots \cr
}$$
rounded to 53 bits on a binary64 machine, which yields,
$$1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001$$
If we compare them side by side,

```
1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001110011...
1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

we see that the 54th & 55th bits cause the 53rd bit to be rounded up to `1`, just as the OP suggested.  Hence

```
x = 0.0000000000000002
% + 1
% - 1
```

has a nonzero final result, namely `2.^-52`.
On the other hand, in $1. + 1. * 10^{-16}$, there is another `0` between the first and second `1`s, so that the 54th & up bits are `01...`. Thus the 53rd bit is rounded to `0`, and the result is `1.`.  Subtracting `1` from it yields zero, as in the OP's first example.

Answer (score 2):

### What happens when adding 1 to a number close to MachineEpsilon?

Some of the confusion in the question is caused by the way Mathematica displays machine-precision numbers. For example, Mathematica's "nice" default settings make it appear that there's no difference between `1.0` and `1.0 + $MachineEpsilon`.

```
1.0
1.0 + $MachineEpsilon
```

The displayed results are the same, that is, `1.`. However, we can use `RealDigits` to show that `1.0 + $MachineEpsilon` is not the same as `1.0` at machine-precision (assuming MachinePrecision is $\frac{53 \log (2)}{\log (10)}$≈15.9546).

```
RealDigits[1.0, 2] (* binary digits *)
RealDigits[1.0 + $MachineEpsilon, 2]
```

The results are:

```
{{1, 0, <<50 zeros>>, 0}, 1} (* least-significant digit is 0 *)
{{1, 0, <<50 zeros>>, 1}, 1} (* least-significant digit is 1 *)
```

The least-significant binary digit shows that `1.0` and `1.0 + $MachineEpsilon` are in fact different, and demonstrates that [MachineEpsilon](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MachineEpsilon.html) is "the minimum positive machine-precision number which can be added to 1.0 to give a result distinguishable from 1.0."

The point is that we can't rely on Mathematica's "nice" display of machine-precision numbers. We need to look as closely as possible at the binary result.

### Case #1, where `x = 0.0000000000000001`

Consider the result of adding 1 to 0.0000000000000001.

```
x = 0.0000000000000001;
RealDigits[x + 1, 2]}
```

The result is `{{1, 0, <<50 zeroes>> 0}, 1}`, and notice the least-significant digit is 0.

### Case #2, where `x = 0.0000000000000002`

```
x = 0.0000000000000002;
RealDigits[x + 1, 2]
```

This time, the result is `{{1, 0, <<50 zeros>> 1}, 1}`. Compare to case #1, where the least-significant digit was 0. This shows how decimal-to-binary conversion and using a number twice as large as case #1 produces a different result, and that the result is MachineEpsilon larger.

The different least-significant binary digits are the reason why the case #2 result isn't zero, and it is in fact the same as MachineEpsilon.

The case where x = 0.0000000000000003 is the same as x = 0.0000000000000002.

```
x = 0.0000000000000003;
RealDigits[x + 1, 2]
```

Another way to look at these results is to use extended-precision numbers instead of machine-precision values. For example, using case #2:

```
x = 0.0000000000000002;
SetPrecision[x + 1, 22]
```

The result is `1.000000000000000222045`. Notice the the digits 222045 from the value of MachineEpsilon.

To summarize, Mathematica displays machine-precision numbers in a "nice" way that doesn't show the full precision of the result of a calculation. We need to use `RealDigits` or use extended precision to see the results of adding 1 to numbers close to MachineEpsilon.

### Is MachineEpsilon the same as on any computer using Mathematica?

The value of MachineEpsilon is determined by the internal representation of machine-precision floating-point numbers. The value of MachinePrecision is $\frac{53 \log (2)}{\log (10)}$≈15.9546, when a computer uses [IEEE Standard 754-1985](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) double-precision, 64-bit floating-point numbers. The value 53 comes from the number of bits used to store the mantissa (52) plus an assumed, normalized 1 bit to the left of the binary mantissa.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `$MachinePrecision` and `$MachineEpsilon` are inconsistent with each other.

Logically `MachineEpsilon` should be equal to $\frac{1}{10^{$MachinePrecision}}$ but in fact `MachineEpsilon` = $ \frac{2}{10^{$MachinePrecision}} $

[image]

So in fact when you multiply your number by 2 you get a number that is larger than the smallest allowed number by `MachinePrecision`.

Also the threshold that @Dede found correspond to `$MachineEpsilon/2` Which in fact the (*effective* `$MachineEpsilon`) = $\frac{1}{10^{$MachinePrecision}}$ and not whatever `$MachineEpsilon` evaluates to in *Mathematica* on my machine.

I think this is due to the fact that one has to deal with negative and positive values so you get the 2 times larger `$MachineEpsilon`

As to your second question: `MachinePrecision` is basically double precision floating point representation which means each number gets 8 bytes.

Comment: `$MachineEpsilon` is 2^(-n+1), where n is the number of binary bits used in the internal representation of machine-precision floating-point numbers (see [$MachineEpsilon documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MachineEpsilon.html)). `$MachinePrecision` is the number of decimal digits of precision used for machine-precision numbers (see [$MachinePrecision documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MachinePrecision.html)). The two numbers are related as you noticed, but there is no inconsistency.